# Проблема с зависимостями sqlalchemy

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlalchemy, проектирование, sql

Добрый день. Необходимо реализовать базу данных при помощи sqlalchemy так, чтобы к одному родительскому классу относились сразу три экземпляра другого. То есть что-то вроде этого:

```
class Lesson(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'lessons'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    ring_start = #Ссылка на первый экземпляр Ring
    ring_end = #Ссылка на второй экземпляр Ring
    ring_warning = #Ссылка на третий экземпляр Ring

class Ring(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rings'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    time = Column(Time)
    lesson = #Ссылка на родителя
```

Как мне кажется, ни один из примеров в [официальных доках](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html) мне не подходит. Может быть кто-нибудь предложит простое и элегантное решение?

p.s. Использовать что-либо кроме sqlalchemy не вариант, т.к. на нем уже многое завязано.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте!

Приведенный пример я понимаю немного иначе с точки зрения реализации.
Рассмотреть `Ring` как родителя, а `Lesson` как на ссылающуюся таблицу.

Тогда `Lesson` в декларативном виде можно реализовать так:

```
class Lesson(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'lessons'
    id            = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name          = Column(String)

    # далее ссылки, возможно пустые
    ring_start    = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('rings.id'), nullable = True)
    ring_end      = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('rings.id'), nullable = True)
    ring_warning  = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('rings.id'), nullable = True)

    def __init__(self, name, ring_start=None, ring_end=None, ring_warning=None):
        ...
    def __repr__(self):
        ...
```

`Ring` соответственно:

```
class Ring(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rings'
    id            = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    time          = Column(Time, server_default = text("now()"))
# (1)   lesson        = relationship("Lesson")
# (2)   lesson        = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('lessons.id'), nullable = True)

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def __repr__(self):
        ...
```

Вопрос остается в обратной связи, напрашивающиеся варианты которой в `Ring` закомментированы. Первый вариант приводится документации и не подходит в чистом виде, т.к. внешних связей между `Ring` и `Lesson` несколько. Второй — из-за зацикливания, даже не смотря на то, что ссылки могут хранить `null`.

Есть способ побороть первый вариант. Для этого функции `relationship` необходимо явно указать по какому правилу искать ссылающиеся объекты.

Например (заменяем строку **(1)**):

```
lesson = relationship("Lesson", primaryjoin="Lesson.ring_start==Ring.id")
```

В таком случае из `Ring.lesson` будут доступны все объекты `Lesson`, в которых `ring_start` совпадает с `Ring.id`.

Другой вариант позволяет получить доступ к любому объекту `Lesson` в котором упоминается текущий `Ring`.

```
lesson = relationship("Lesson", primaryjoin="or_(Lesson.ring_start==Ring.id,"
                                            "Lesson.ring_end==Ring.id,"
                                            "Lesson.ring_warning==Ring.id)")
```

Можно сделать несколько переменных `Ring.lesson*`, например:

```
lesson_start = relationship("Lesson", primaryjoin="Lesson.ring_start==Ring.id")
lesson_end   = relationship("Lesson", primaryjoin="Lesson.ring_end==Ring.id")
```

Надеюсь, чем-нибудь помогла.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вам поможет [официальная документация](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths) там как раз описан именно ваш случай

````
```import datetime

class Ring(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rings'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    time: Mapped[datetime.time] = mapped_column(Time)


class Lesson(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'lessons'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)

    ring_start_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("rings.id"))
    ring_start: Mapped["Ring"] = relationship(foreign_keys=[ring_start_id])

    ring_end_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("rings.id"))
    ring_end: Mapped["Ring"] = relationship(foreign_keys=[ring_end_id])
   
    ring_warning_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("rings.id"))
    ring_warning: Mapped["Ring"] = relationship(foreign_keys=[ring_warning_id])```
````